# shiny: select and mark pictures the same way you mark photos in the gallery of a phone

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny app to load pictures and I should be able to select some of the images by clicking on them and the selected images will be recorded.
I want a function that I can select and mark pictures the same way you mark photos in the gallery of a phone.

Currently, I made an app that the selected images are replaced by an empty icon. Here is what I have tried:

```
  ui <-fluidPage(column(
                  width=9,
                  align="center",
                  imageOutput(outputId = "img1", click = clickOpts(id = "img1_click", clip = FALSE),width = 150,height = 150,inline = TRUE)
                  ,imageOutput(outputId = "img2", click = clickOpts(id = "img2_click", clip = FALSE),width = 150,height = 150,inline = TRUE)
                  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  empty_img="/empty.jpeg"
  vals=reactiveValues(img=list.files("/images/"))
  vals2=reactiveValues(img=list.files("/images/"))
                      
  empty_img_to_normal_value=reactiveValues(m=1:length(vals$img))
      output$img1 <- renderImage({
        list(src = vals$img[1], width = "200", height = "200") } ,deleteFile = FALSE)
      observeEvent(input$img1_click, {
        if(empty_img_to_normal_value$m[1]==1){
          vals$img[1]=empty_img
          empty_img_to_normal_value$m[1]=0
        }else{ 
          vals$img[1]=vals2$img[1]
          empty_img_to_normal_value$m[1]=1
        }
      })
      
      output$img2 <- renderImage({
        list(src = vals$img[2], width = "200", height = "200")} ,deleteFile = FALSE)
      observeEvent(input$img2_click, {
          if(empty_img_to_normal_value$m[2]==1){
            vals$img[2]=empty_img
            empty_img_to_normal_value$m[2]=0
          }else{ 
            vals$img[2]=vals2$img[2]
            empty_img_to_normal_value$m[2]=1
          }
      })  
    }
```

Comment: I think you could do a module showing your image with a unlabelled checkbox on top right of it, and return the value of the checkbox. Then you call your module for each of your images in your main app

Comment: Thanks @gdevaux, could you please give me some keywords to search for how to render images with another element? I can't use plotoutput because I have to render 150 images, which slows down the process significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Following our comments, I made a proper answer.

```
# list of images URLs, replace them with your images
lst_urls <- list("data/Rplot1.png", "data/Rplot1.png", "data/Rplot1.png", "data/Rplot1.png",
                 "data/Rplot5.png","data/Rplot5.png","data/Rplot5.png","data/Rplot5.png")

img_w <- "100%"
img_h <- 200

mod_img_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$style(".checkbox{margin-bottom: -40px;}"),
    column(
      width =2,
      checkboxInput(
        inputId = ns("select_img"), label = NULL
      ),
      imageOutput(
        outputId = ns("img"), width = img_w, height = img_h, inline = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}

mod_img_SERVER <- function(input, output, session, img_url){
  ns <- session$ns
  output$img <- renderImage({
    list(src = img_url,
         alt = "This is alternate text",
         width = img_w,
         height = img_h,
         contentType = "image/png")
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  return(input$select_img)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
      uiOutput("images")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$images <- renderUI({
    lapply(
      1:length(lst_urls),
      function(i) {
        mod_img_UI(id = paste0("img", i))
      }
    )
  })

  observe({
    selected_imgs <- lapply(
      1:length(lst_urls),
      function(i) {
        callModule(
          module = mod_img_SERVER,
          session = session,
          id = paste0("img", i),
          img_url = lst_urls[[i]]
        )
      }
    )
    print(paste("You picked :",lst_urls[unlist(selected_imgs)]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it works beautifully thanks a lot.